# Netezza - Join 2 tables where Dates don't match

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm unclear regarding a join approach based on the following:

I have the following 2 recordsets and looking to create the listed result set.

[image]

I would join on [Symbol] and ??? for each [Rec_ID] and return the active [Value_int] for the [Effective_dt] prior to (or) equal to the [Record_Dt].  Is there a way to use JOINs to achieve this?  INNER JOIN would be fine since I do not need to return a value if no [Effectivedt] was found that preceded a [Record_Dt].  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have discovered, TOP and and that particular form of correlated subquery don't work in Netezza.

An approach that will work in Netezza is to join to a subquery using LAG.

```
SELECT a.rec_id,
   a.symbol,
   b.value_int
FROM tableA a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT symbol,
            value_int,
            eff_dt,
            lag(eff_dt, 1,'3999-01-01'::DATE) over (partition BY symbol ORDER BY eff_dt DESC) end_eff_dt
         FROM tableB
      )
      b
   ON a.symbol      = b.symbol
   AND a.record_dt >= b.eff_dt
   AND a.record_dt  < b.end_eff_dt
ORDER BY rec_id;

 REC_ID | SYMBOL | VALUE_INT
--------+--------+-----------
      1 | A      |      1094
      2 | A      |   2523423
      3 | A      |    643532
      4 | A      |    643532
      5 | B      |     34242
      6 | B      |    534632
      7 | B      |   8567555
      8 | B      |      5665
      9 | B      |
(9 rows)
```

What you're doing looks an awful lot like referencing a slowly changing dimension. If so, you should consider precalculating then next/end effective date as part of your ETL, and storing it in tableB for a more efficient query.

Comment: Simply awesome.  Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

I was able produce your expectation with a subquery in the query. I don't think there is a way to do this with ONLY joins.

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA
    (
     rec_id int, 
     symbol varchar(20), 
     record_dt datetime
    );

CREATE TABLE #tableB
    (     
     symbol varchar(20), 
     value_int int,
     eff_dt datetime
    );

INSERT INTO #tableA
(rec_id, symbol, record_dt)
VALUES
(1, 'A', '10-01-2014'),
(2, 'A', '07-10-2014'),
(3, 'A', '04-01-2014'),
(4, 'A', '03-27-2014'),
(5, 'B', '09-02-2014'),
(6, 'B', '08-30-2014'),
(7, 'B', '04-01-2014'),
(8, 'B', '02-20-2014'),
(8, 'B', '01-01-2014');

INSERT INTO #tableB
(symbol, value_int, eff_dt)
VALUES
('A', 1094, '09-02-2014'),
('A', 328087, '08-18-2014'),
('A', 2523423, '05-21-2014'),
('A', 643532, '03-27-2014'),
('B', 34242, '09-02-2014'),
('B', 534632, '08-18-2014'),
('B', 22342, '05-21-2014'),
('B', 8567555, '03-27-2014'),
('B', 5665, '01-10-2014');

SELECT a.rec_id
, a.symbol
, (SELECT TOP 1 value_int
from #tableB b 
WHERE a.symbol = b.symbol and a.record_dt >= b.eff_dt
order by b.eff_dt desc )
FROM #tableA a

DROP TABLE #tableA
DROP TABLE #tableB
```